# how to do a void function that receive struct pointer for modify how many struct variable?

Tags: c

I've a week coding a void function that receive a struct like reference parameter and with calloc/malloc modify how many struct variables create, but i have a error in the parameter reference.
Note: I coding from android app.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTPdM.jpg)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Student{
    char name[50];
    int age;
    int semester;
   char group;
};

void ModifyVar(struct Student *St);

int main(){
    struct Student *St1;
    ModifyVar(&St1)
    return 0;
}

void ModifyVar(struct Student *St){
    int N;
    printf("How many Students\nAns: ");
    scanf("%d",&N);
    *St = calloc(N,sizeof(Student));
}
```

Comment: do not insert pictures in the question, insert a real code characters so that one can cut-n-paste them. In any case you need `struct Student **St`, two stars, not one in ModifyVar.

Answer (score 1):

You want to modify the value of `St1` in `ModifyVar` in `C`, so you must pass the **pointer** of `St1` to `ModifyVar`. And `St1` is a pointer, `struct Student *`, so you have to pass `&St1` whose type is `struct Student **`. Now, you should know that the prototype of `ModifyVar` should be `void ModifyVar(struct Student **)`. Also, I think you should note your coding style.

Comment: Yep, I tried this, but it failed, because when I read the values inside struct, the running stop but thanks for all

Comment: @MiguelHumberto Then you did something else wrong when trying to read values.  That would be a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
void ModifyVar(struct Student *St)
```

To

```
void ModifyVar(struct Student **St)    //pointer to pointer
```

Or use like this

```
struct student * AllocMem()
{
    int N;
    printf("How many Students\nAns: ");
    scanf("%d",&N);
    return (calloc(N,sizeof(struct student));
}
```

call like ths

```
St1 = AllocMem();
```

And check the memory is allocated or not by

```
 if(St1==NULL)
 {
    printf("calloc() failed");
    exit(1);
 }
```

And don't forgot to free the allocated memory by

```
free(St1);
```

> I did, but maybe my android compiler doesn't run

What did you tried See full code below are you changed prototype and add the semicolon ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Student
{
    char name[50];
    int age;
    int semester;
   char group;
};

void ModifyVar(struct Student **St);

int main()
{
    struct Student *St1;
    ModifyVar(&St1);
    free(St1);
    return 0;
}

void ModifyVar(struct Student **St) 
{
    int N;
    printf("How many Students\nAns: ");
    scanf("%d",&N);
    *St = calloc(N,sizeof(struct Student));
}
```

[See this Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/SktHQ_DiU)

Thanks.

Comment: Ummm... I did, but maybe my android compiler doesn't run

Comment: @Miguel Humberto   Feel free to accept any of the answers if you got it.

Answer (score -1):

In main, just do this instead:

```
struct Student *St1;
    ModifyVar(St1);
```

St1 is already a pointer and you are using the address of (`&St1`) operator to again get the address of the pointer not the pointer itself. So you're passing a pointer to struct pointer instead of a plain pointer to struct.

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Be sure to upvote the helpful answers and accept one of the answers if your problem is solved :)